# Count how many non-zero numbers are in string

Tags: c#, string, numbers

I have this string:

> 0374:0462:0469:0354:0411:0433:0704:0391:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:

I would like to find out how many non-zero numbers (separated by ":") are inside it.

It should output "8".

Comment: Use logic, break the problem apart in to smaller solveable steps. First figure out how to get all of the numbers, then figure out how to check to see if that number is zero, then figure out how to add up the total number of numbers that where not zero.

Comment: What language? Would make an answer more valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = str.Split(':').Where(x => !x.All(c => c == '0')).Count();
```

Or you can use [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) alternatively:

```
var result = str.Split(':').Count(x => x.Trim('0').Any());
```

Comment: or the other way around: `int count = str.Split(':').Count(x => x.All(Char.IsDigit) && x.Any(c => c != '0'));`

Comment: @TimSchmelter you right it is more safe if the input contains non-digit characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
var count = input.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count(x => int.Parse(x) != 0);
```

Comment: Which also fails on invalid numbers like `123abc`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = src.Split(':').Count(c => c.All(char.IsDigit) && c.Any(x => x != '0'));
```

Comment: Which also counts words like `123abc` but OP wants only "non-zero numbers".